# Expectation of the time difference between starting times in queueing theory

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, expectation, queueing-theory

Consider 2 independent, parallel $M/M/1$ queues $Q_1, Q_2$ with identical arrival rate $\lambda$ (corresponding to an exponential random variable $A \sim \text{Exp}(\lambda)$) and service rate $\mu$ (corresponding to an exponential random variable $S \sim \text{Exp}(\mu)$). For each $M/M/1$ queue, we use the FCFS (First Come First Served) discipline and if there is some customer in service, no more customers can enter it.

For each customer $c$, its start time, service time, and service interval are denoted by $c_{st}, c_{ft},$ and $[c_{st}, c_{ft}]$, respectively.

For two customers $w$ served by $Q_1$ and $r$ served by $Q_2$, suppose that $r$ starts between $w$'s service interval (i.e., $r_{st} \in [{w}_{st}, {w}_{ft}]$) and the difference between their start times ${r}_{st} - {w}_{st}$ follows an exponential random variable $D$ with rate $\lambda$ (see the figure below).

Let $r'$ be the last previous customer served by $Q_2$ just before the one $r$.

> ***Problem:*** What is the expectation of $D' = r'_{st} - {w}_{st}$, the time difference between the starts times of $r'$ and $w$?

[image: two-queues-probability]

---

***My trial:*** $\mathbb{E}(D') = \mathbb{E}(r'_{ft} - r'_{st}) + \mathbb{E}(r_{st} - r'_{ft}) - \mathbb{E}(D) = \frac{1}{\mu} + \mathbb{E}(A_1 \mid A_1 < A_2) - \frac{1}{\lambda}) = \frac{1}{\mu} + \frac{3}{2\lambda} - \frac{1}{\lambda} = \frac{1}{2\lambda} + \frac{1}{\mu},$ where $A_1$ and $A_2$ are i.i.d. random variables with common distribution as $A$.
Does this make sense?

Comment: I think that should be $+\mathbb E[D]$ there instead of $-$, since that would yield $\mathbb E[r'_{st}-w_{st}]$.

Comment: @Math1000 I get my formula (with $-\mathbb{E}[D]$) just from the intuitive, visual relations between the interval lengths of $D', [r'_{ft} - r'_{st}], [r_{st}-r'_{ft}]$, and $D$. Do you mean that this intuition does not hold actually? Could you please elaborate on your idea, especially on the term $+\mathbb{E}[D]$? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I made an. What I was trying to point out is that
$$\begin{align*}
(r'_{ft}-r'_{st})+(r_{st}-r'_{ft}-(r'_{st}-w_{st}) &= (r'_{ft}-r'_{ft}) + (r_{st} - r_{st}) + (w_{st}-r'_{st})\\
&= w_{st} - r'_{st}\\
&= -D'.
\end{align*}$$
So the expression should be $$\mathbb E[D] - \mathbb E[r'_{ft}-r'_{st}] - \mathbb E[r_{st}-r'_{ft}]. $$

Comment: @Math1000 Yes. I missed a negative sign. Thanks. Convert your comment to an answer? By the way, a typo perhaps: $r'_{st} - w_{st}$ should be $r_{st} - w_{st}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
$$\begin{align*}
D' &= r'_{st} - w_{st}\\
&= (r'_{st} - w_{st}) + (r_{st}-r_{st}) + (r'_{ft}-r'_{ft})\\
&= (r_{st} - w_{st}) - (r'_{ft}-r'_{st}) - (r_{st}-r'_{ft})\\
&= D - (r'_{ft}-r'_{st}) - (r_{st}-r'_{ft}).
\end{align*}$$
Hence $$\begin{align*}\mathbb E[D'] &= \mathbb E[D] - \mathbb E[r'_{ft}-r'_{st}] - \mathbb E[r_{st}-r'_{ft}]\\
&= \frac1\lambda -\frac1\mu -\frac1{2\lambda}\\
&= \frac{\mu-2\lambda}{2\lambda\mu}.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: I found that $\mathbb E[A_1 | A_1<A_2]=\frac1{2\lambda}$, not $\frac3{2\lambda}$, by the way.

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake again. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome!